# How to split a cell into two based on the values present in a third cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on Excel 2019.

I've **two columns** on my Excel file:

> SURNAME AND NAME | TAX ID CODE    |

I need to **split the surname and name** into two cells based on the **TAX ID CODE**.

Surname can be made of multiple words, the same goes for names, however some parameters from the **TAX ID CODE** of my country are structured with predefined rules.

For the previous name it would be like this.

> Mohammad Ali Abdul | MHMLBD1G10B85H1S

Surname and name can be of an unlimited number of characters however the TAX ID CODE is always formed by 16 characters; the first 6 characters are made by the **Surname(char 1,2,3)** and the Name **(char 4,5,6)**.
The **TAX ID CODE** always prefers consonants over vowels, and thus are always the first ones that will be chosen to form it.
The seventh to sixteenth characters of the TAX ID CODE are useless for my query.

In the example above, the TAX ID CODE would choose MHM by taking into consideration the surname Mohammad, and LBD for the name ALI ABDUL.

In some (not that rare) exceptions, such is the case of names with fewer than three consonants, the TAX ID CODE will choose the first appearing vowels.

E.g.

Olaf Gandalf -> would turn out to be OLFGND.

In rarer exceptions, such as surnames and names with less than three characters, the TAX ID CODE will use "X" as replacement.

E.g.
**Surname = Bo Marcus -> TAX ID CODE would be = BOXMRC**

Also, the TAX ID CODE always uses the first (first) name, and in case of multiple surnames, the first surname as its source.

E.g.
White Rodrick James -> WHTRDR
It would only take into consideration the first name and only in lack of enough consonants first, and vowel next, would it take into consideration the second name;
if that too lacks content, the "X" character will be the one used to fill the gap.

I'm trying create a script to split the Surname and the Name by running a cycle that takes into consideration the char 4,5,6 of the TAX ID CODE to analyze the name string by starting from the end of it.
Once it pairs the set of three characters with the first relatable name,
it would then split the cell into two by using the correctly analyzed name as the starting point for the output of the second column,
while the first would contain only the surname.

The characters that take into consideration the name skip the first appearance of the second consonant.
E.g.
Abdul Abdullah would turn out to be BDL BLL
Abdullam Abdul Abdel would turn out to be BDL BLB

Comment: Names are known for making coding hard. What is to say that the 2nd set of three characters that make up the name also can't be found at the end (or in a 2nd part) of the surname, thus potentially splitting the name at the wrong index. I don't think there is a correct way to know for sure what the end of the surname is and where the name would start.

Comment: e.g: "Abdullam Abdul Abdel". With "BDLBDL". What is to say the surname is not "Abdullam Abdul" *or* "Abdullam" on itself...

Comment: thank you for the feedback, it reminded me that I skipped a part. Hopefully it's enough to make it a little more viable. Anyway I added it at the end of the thread.

Comment: Even with that edit, I think you cannot rule out that there are plenty of potential names you just can't split based on these set of rules. I'd love to be proven wrong though =)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid there is no pattern you can code to get this because there are so many cases available. The only way would be coding almost each case and that's a terrible work

Comment: So as it seems it really can't be fully automated :(. I guess I'll keep on having to check the records in case of mistakes.
Thank you guys, and thank you the welcome, much appreciated.

Comment: I too think that it can't be fully automated to an error-proof level. It doesn't mean one can't try to automate it with a fair level of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I've put down a first draft of a code that works with every example you have given so far:

```
Option Explicit
Function FunNameSplit(StrTaxIDCode As String)
    
    Dim StrFullName As String
    Dim StrIDName As String
    Dim StrIDSurname As String
    Dim BytCounter01 As Byte
    Dim BytCounter02 As Byte
    Dim StrCharacter01 As String
    Dim StrPossibleSurname As String
    Dim StrFullNameChop As String
    Dim StrNameSecondConsonant As String
    Dim StrMarker As String
    
    StrMarker = "|"
    StrIDSurname = VBA.Strings.Left(VBA.Strings.Right(StrTaxIDCode, 16), 3)
    StrIDName = VBA.Strings.Left(VBA.Strings.Right(StrTaxIDCode, 13), 3)
    StrFullName = Split(StrTaxIDCode, " | ")(0)
    StrPossibleSurname = StrFullName
    
    For BytCounter01 = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFullName, " ")) - 1
        
        StrFullNameChop = VBA.StrReverse(Split(VBA.StrReverse(StrFullName), " ")(BytCounter01)) & " " & StrFullNameChop
        
        If Right(StrFullNameChop, 1) = " " Then StrFullNameChop = Left(StrFullNameChop, Len(StrFullNameChop) - 1)
        
        
        
        StrNameSecondConsonant = ""
        StrPossibleSurname = Left(StrPossibleSurname, Len(StrPossibleSurname) - Len(VBA.StrReverse(Split(VBA.StrReverse(StrPossibleSurname), " ")(0))) - 1)
        
        
        If Right(StrPossibleSurname, 1) = " " Then StrPossibleSurname = Left(StrPossibleSurname, Len(StrPossibleSurname) - 1)
        
        For BytCounter02 = 1 To Len(StrPossibleSurname)
            StrCharacter01 = UCase(Mid(StrPossibleSurname, BytCounter02, 1))
            If StrCharacter01 = "A" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "E" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "I" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "O" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "U" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = " " _
            Then
                
            Else
                
                If StrNameSecondConsonant <> "" Then
                    StrNameSecondConsonant = StrCharacter01
                    GoTo CP_Second_Consonant_Found
                Else
                    StrNameSecondConsonant = " "
                End If
                
            End If
        Next
CP_Second_Consonant_Found:
        
        
        If FunFindMatch(UCase(StrIDName), Replace(UCase(StrFullNameChop), StrNameSecondConsonant, " ", , 1)) = True Then
            
            FunNameSplit = FunNameSplit & Left(StrFullName, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(Len(StrFullName) - Len(StrFullNameChop) - 1, 0)) & StrMarker & StrFullNameChop & StrMarker & StrMarker
            
        End If
    Next
    
End Function
Private Function FunFindMatch(StrWhat As String, StrWhere As String)
    
    Dim BytCounter01 As Byte
    Dim BytPosition As Byte
    Dim BytTarget As Byte
    Dim StrInput01 As String
    Dim StrInput02 As String
    Dim StrCharacter01 As String
    Dim BlnVowel As Boolean
    
    StrInput01 = Left(StrWhat, Len(StrWhere))
    StrInput02 = StrWhere
    BytPosition = 1
    
    For BytCounter01 = 1 To Len(StrInput01)
        
        If StrInput02 = VBA.Replace(StrInput02, VBA.Strings.Mid(StrInput01, BytCounter01, 1), " ") Then
            FunFindMatch = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        BytTarget = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Find(VBA.Strings.Mid(StrInput01, BytCounter01, 1), StrInput02)
        
        If BytTarget >= BytPosition Then
            
            StrCharacter01 = Mid(StrInput02, BytTarget, 1)
            If StrCharacter01 = "A" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "E" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "I" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "O" Or _
               StrCharacter01 = "U" _
            Then
                BlnVowel = True
            Else
                BlnVowel = False
            End If
            
            StrInput02 = Replace(StrInput02, VBA.Strings.Mid(StrInput01, BytCounter01, 1), " ", , 1)
            
            For BytPosition = BytPosition To BytTarget
                
                StrCharacter01 = Mid(StrInput02, BytPosition, 1)
                If StrCharacter01 = "A" Or _
                   StrCharacter01 = "E" Or _
                   StrCharacter01 = "I" Or _
                   StrCharacter01 = "O" Or _
                   StrCharacter01 = "U" _
                Then
                    
                    If BlnVowel Then
                        If StrCharacter01 <> " " Then
                            FunFindMatch = False
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                    
                Else
                    
                    If StrCharacter01 <> " " Then
                        FunFindMatch = False
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
                
            Next
            
        Else
            
            FunFindMatch = False
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    FunFindMatch = True
    
End Function
```

Place it in a VBA module and then use the function FunNameSplit in a cell. The element StrTaxIDCode must be the full tax ID code (or the cell containing it). The result will be a string with name and surname separated by a mark (this mark being "|"). In case of multiple possible valid combination, they will be all listed one after the other separeted by a double mark (then "||"). Send feedback.

[image]

Comment: This was really, really helpful. I just got back from a little trip away from job, so I pretty much just saw, it, but looking at it, I can already say that it will help me greatly. Thank you very much Evil Blue Monkey.

Comment: You're welcome. Send feedback whenever you have any.